# overwrite a single core data attribute

Tags: swift, core-data, attributes, overwrite

My goal is to overwrite a single value from a core data attribute. My swift code below fetches a value but I dont know how to overwrite it.

```
           func getBool(imageNo:Int) {
    // first check the array bounds
    let info = helpBool.shareInstance.fetchBool()
    if info.count > imageNo {
        // if info[imageNo].bool {
        if info[imageNo].bool == true {
            checkmarkButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"unnamed"), for: .normal);
            
        }
        
        if info[imageNo].bool == false {
            
            checkmarkButton.setImage(nil, for: .normal);
        }
        // }
        
        
        
    }
}




            }

         class helpBool: UIViewController{

static let shareInstance = helpBool()
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext







func fetchBool() -> [OnOff] {
    
  
    var fetchingImage = [OnOff]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "OnOff")
    
    do {
        
        fetchingImage = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [OnOff]
    } catch {
        print("Error while fetching the image")
    }
    
    return fetchingImage
}
```

I want to overwrite the 2nd value that is it from a false to true value. I have attached a photo if that makes anything easier to understand.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The object `fetchingImage` which you acquired from `context.fetch()` is connected with your database so every change you make to it is reflected to your database but you need to call `context.save()` when you finish editing the values you want to edit.

Here is an example of the edit function and remember that `item` should be from the array `info` which you acquired from `getBool()`

```
func editBool(item: OnOff, newValue: Bool) {
    // edit your item here , bool and/or other attributes you want to edit
    item.bool = newValue
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Error while changing the value")
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

For more about CoreData I would suggest this video on YouTube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjHBINtpKA8

Comment: i need to change the 2nd item of onoff how do i do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by that so please supply the code for class `OnOff` for further explanation.